# Exchange 2010 org subdomain mail routing fail

Tags: email, routing, exchange-2010

I have a central setup with EX2010 and with a separate system as an edge transport, serving email addresses for aa.domain.com and domain.com.
For some reason, this means I am unable to send email to another domain, hosted externally for now, called bb.domain.com

I'd be grateful for any pointers, whether on how to troubleshoot this, or how to configure this properly